# Swift: Convert 2D array to array of custom objects

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

,

```
let languages = ["en", "ru", "pt"]

let sheetValues = [["key", "general_ok", "connection_nointernet_message"], ["en", "Ok", "No internet connection"], ["ru", "russianOk", "No internet connection"], ["pt", "portugueseOk", "No internet connection"], ["description", "Ok", "No internet connection"], ["section", "General", "Connection"]]
```

I can manipulate `sheetValues`  to be fetched as its transpose (if needed)

What I want is below:

```
[
    [
        "isoCode": "en",
        "data": [SheetData("key": "general_ok", "value": "Ok", "description": "Ok", "section": "General"),
                 SheetData("key": "connection_nointernet_message", "value": "No internet connection", "description": "No internet connection", "section": "Conenction")]

    ],
    [
        "isoCode": "ru",
        "data": [SheetData("key": "general_ok", "value": "russianOk", "description": "Ok", "section": "General"),
                 SheetData("key": "connection_nointernet_message", "value": "No internet connection", "description": "No internet connection", "section": "Conenction")]

    ],
    [
        "isoCode": "pt",
        "data": [SheetData("key": "general_ok", "value": "portugueseOk", "description": "Ok", "section": "General"),
                 SheetData("key": "connection_nointernet_message", "value": "No internet connection", "description": "No internet connection", "section": "Conenction")]
    ]
]
```

Models:

```
struct Language {
    var isoCode: String?
    var data: [SheetData]?
}

struct SheetData {
    let key: String
    let value: String
    var description: String?
    let section: String
}
```

This is what I have currently, any clean way to get the needed (i.e `[SheetData]`)?

```
func fetchLanguages() -> [Language] {
    var allLanguages = [Language]()

    for sheetValue in sheetValues {
        var language = Language()
        var allDataPoints = [SheetData]()

        if let firstElement = sheetValue.first {
            if languages.contains(firstElement) {
                language.isoCode = firstElement
            }
        }

        allLanguages.append(language)
    }

    return allLanguages
}
```

Comment: This is such a mess, you should do something about your input. Where does the content of `sheetValues` come from?

Comment: Haha, yes. From a google sheet - reading the data as columns

Comment: Maybe you should create your SheetData objects directly when reading the data from the sheet instead of first storing it in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have looked at your data and come up with a solution. The `result` value at the end should have the array you wanted.

```
        // First create a dictionary with keys for each language
        // In case new languages added or removed
        let languages = ["en", "ru", "pt"]
        var datas: [String: [String: Any]] = [:]
        for language in languages {
            var sheetData: [String: Any] = [:]
            sheetData["isoCode"] = language
            sheetData["data"] = []

            datas[language] = sheetData
        }

        // Get your sheetValues from your source. Here I just used the array you provided.
        let sheetValues = [["key", "general_ok", "connection_nointernet_message"],
                           ["en", "Ok", "No internet connection"],
                           ["ru", "russianOk", "No internet connection"],
                           ["pt", "portugueseOk", "No internet connection"],
                           ["description", "Ok", "No internet connection"],
                           ["section", "General", "Connection"]]

        // Loop the sheetValues starting from index 1 since index 0 holds the key values. 
        for i in 1..<sheetValues.count {
            let languageKey = sheetValues[i][0]
            if datas.keys.contains(languageKey) {
                let firstSheetData = SheetData(key: sheetValues[0][1], // general_ok
                                               value: sheetValues[i][1], // Ok, russianOk etc
                                               description: sheetValues[sheetValues.count - 2][1], // Ok
                                               section: sheetValues[sheetValues.count - 1][1]) // General

                let secondSheetData = SheetData(key: sheetValues[0][2], // connection_nointernet_message
                                                value: sheetValues[i][2], // No internet connection
                                                description: sheetValues[sheetValues.count - 2][2], // No internet connection
                                                section: sheetValues[sheetValues.count - 1][2]) // Connection

                datas[languageKey]["data"] = [firstSheetData, secondSheetData]
            }
        }

        // Loop the dictioanary holding the language datas
        var result: [[String: Any]] = []
        for (key, value) in datas {
            result.append(value)
        }
```

This solution only works with certain conditions:

- Index 0 of `sheetValues` will always have the `key` values
- Second index from the last in `sheetValues` will always have the `description` values
- Last index of `sheetValues` will always have the `section` values